# Remove CSS files from header - Magento

Tags: php, css, magento, merge, head

My Magento store is loading a lot of css files:
[image: 10 CSS files is used]

I want to combine them into only 1 or 2 css files. I am aware of the merge option in Magento, but that breaks the design completely. So I want to do it manually. Can it simply be done by copying all the css from the files and pasting it in style.css, and then remove the link rel code of the css files no longer needed from the header? In the head.phtml file found in app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html, the lines on the picture is not there, but there is this line `<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>` - but how do I edit out the css files no longer needed?

Answer (score 1):

Go to local.xml file and remove what are css files you don't need?

Comment: I think I can figure out how to remove it via local.xml, but wouldn't it be better to remove it from the place where it adds the css files, so it is not added from the start? Instead of adding and then removing again? What I would like to know, is where I find the code that tells all thos css files to be loaded, and edit it there :)

Comment: @aaimport - No, because you end up with a convoluted mess of edited files that can be completely left alone. If you don't edit them, they don't become an issue on upgrading. Always use local.xml, it's held in Magento cache and the imagined extra work for Magento just isn't there, whereas the additional makework from editing things that should be left alone becomes an intense headache later down the road. Our original developer did what you proposed and the problems didn't go away until their garbage editing went away.

Comment: I see your point. I think I will remove them from local.xml then. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from `page.xml` or `local.xml` file. Between below code your css file code should be written.

These file located at
`/app/design/frontend/[theme_folder]/[theme_default]/layout`

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
<!-- css code here -->
</block>
```

remove your css action in .xml files

Comment: I think I can figure out how to remove it via local.xml, but wouldn't it be better to remove it from the place where it adds the css files, so it is not added from the start? Instead of adding and then removing again? What I would like to know, is where I find the code that tells all thos css files to be loaded, and edit it there :)

Comment: why you seems remove from xml is not good ? even magento it self prefer to remove and add css or js from xml.